# How to drop row with bracket in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to drop the `[]` for a given `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,4,[],5]))
```

Such that the expected output will be

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
3  5
```

Edit:

or to make thing more interesting, what if we have two columns and some of the cell is with `[]` to be dropped.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,4,[],5],b=[2,[],1,[],6]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use equality directly as pandas will try to align a Series and a list, but you can use `isin`:

```
df[~df['a'].isin([[]])]
```

output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
4  5
```

To act on all columns:

```
df[~df.isin([[]]).any(1)]
```

output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
2  4  1
4  5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to get the string repr and filter:

```py
df = df[df['a'].map(repr)!='[]']
```

Output:

```py
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
4  5
```

For multiple columns, we could `apply` the above:

```py
out = df[df.apply(lambda c: c.map(repr)).ne('[]').all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```py
   a  b
0  1  2
2  4  1
4  5  6
```

Comment: Hi @enke, thanks for the great suggestion. For the sake of completeness, will these suggestion maintain if there is multiple columns with the bracket? Duplicate since I cannot tag two users under same comment

Comment: @rpb what do you mean? do you have multiple columns with empty list entries?

Comment: ops, sorry,forget to mention that I had amend the post above.

Comment: @rpb I edited the answer. For multiple columns, explode wouldn't work anymore so I removed it. But for multiple columns, mozway's solution will be much more efficient and concise.

Comment: this is going to be significantly slower than the other version